# Excel macro sql query syntax (Datetime)

Tags: sql, excel, datetime, ms-access, syntax-error

I'm having issues with the syntax required for the below query.
Basically just trying to only import data from the access database that is between the selected dates.

The macro works for any other data type (boolean, int etc.) so I'm pretty sure it's not the excel side. But I'm very new to Sql code so have no idea what I'm doing wrong with the query!

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Downtime_Database WHERE (Time_Start >= " & _
    Format(Range("TIMESTART").Value, "d - mmm - yyyythhmm") & _
    ") AND (Time_End <= " & Format(Range("TIMEEND").Value, "d - mmm - yyyythhmm)")
```

TIMESTART and TIMEEND are just named ranges in the sheet that have a standard datetime value in them.

The error that VBA throws is a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression" followed by the above string.

The image below is just a screen cap of the error.

[Error Screen Cap Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiVWs.png)

No Idea what I'm missing or doing wrong, everything else seems to work fine.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper format for passing a datetime value with time to Access SQL is either `"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#"` or `"\#yyyy\-mm\-dd hh\:nn\:ss\#"`

Use either of those in your format function:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Downtime_Database WHERE Time_Start >= " & _
Format(Range("TIMESTART").Value, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#") & _
" AND Time_End <= " & Format(Range("TIMEEND").Value, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")
```

Comment: THANKYOU!
I was looking for exactly this everywhere!